# What is IE7's expected End of Support?

Tags: internet-explorer-7

Seeing as [IE7 has only about 10% of the browser market share](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_7), I was wondering when Microsoft plans on terminating support for it. We have some browser incompatibilities to work through and we're wondering if it's worth the effort for such a small market share...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Support for internet explorer versions are [tied to the support for the OS it shipped with](http://support.microsoft.com/gp/lifean24). The most modern OS which shipped with IE7 is Windows server 2008 and support for that isn't slated to end until [2018](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2008). Ugh.

However you problem isn't really one of the end of support but rather the end of widespread adoption. That is a complex question and depends on what you define as a significant user base and what your users are like. For instance I work in an industry which is traditionally slow to adopt new technology so I still need to support IE6 and will probably have to for 4 years to come. But if only 2% of my revenue came from customers on IE6 I would likely drop support as it costs me more to support it than I am paid. Is it costing you more to support IE7 than the revenue you're getting from those users?

Answer (score 16):

Old question, but a relevant response...

We follow Google's policy of supporting the most recent 2 versions, and dropping the 3rd oldest when a new one comes out.. So that's IE8 and 9 that we have to support today. :)

Several big sites are following this policy now.. so I think you'll find the old browsers are going to start tapering off faster.

Comment: I like this policy, but there is one thing that may cause you problems. Internet Explorer 8 is the latest version you can get for Windows XP. And since Windows XP still has a 25% OS market share, it looks like its not practical to drop support for IE8 when IE10 comes out in the near future

Comment: I think it's foolish to make hard and fast rules like that. You need to look at your site and business goals and weigh the effort to support each browser.

Comment: I disagree. We need hard and fast rules to keep the costs of support IE under control. We all know IE is a sinkhole for developer time, by setting a limit, we control our costs and encourage our customers to use a modern, standards compliant, secure browser.

Comment: +1. However, this answer is only useful if your customers will upgrade. There are developers out there who will more likely lose their main customer(s) with this policy than encourage them to upgrade. I really do pity those developers, but it's a reality for some. The rest of us need to be considering IE8 as an absolute baseline today, and IE9 as a more sensible base going forward, or even IE10.

Answer (score 5):

It was [recently announced](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2014/08/support-for-old-versions-of-internet-explorer-to-be-dropped/) that [support for IE 7 and IE 8 will be ending on 12th January 2016](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/search?sort=PN&alpha=internet%20explorer).

Comment: Can you provide the source for this?

Comment: Source: Microsoft
https://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/search/?sort=PN&alpha=internet+explorer